Python, Agrupar entradas y salidas con Pandas
En Python, se importa de un csv los datos de los eventos de un marcador de huellas digital, el problema es como usar pandas para agrupar las entradas y salidas del mismo día de cada usuario de un mes. Soy nuevo en Python y no se como agruparlos.
Como agrupar los datos de la entradas y salidas tipo así:
ID, Nombre, fecha, entrada1, salida1, entrada2, salida2
1, Ana, 1/5/2024, 7:55, 12:00, 13:00, 17:02

código:
import pandas as pd

datos_originales = pd.read_csv("datos_entrada.csv", delimiter=";")

# Separar fecha y hora
datos_originales[["fecha", "hora"]] = datos_originales["fecha_hora"].str.split(" ", expand=True)

# Crear columna auxiliar con solo la fecha
datos_originales["fecha_sin_hora"] = pd.to_datetime(datos_originales["fecha"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

# Agrupar por empleado y fecha
def create_list(x):
    return [x["hora"].iloc[i] for i in range(len(x))]
    
datos_agrupados = datos_originales.groupby(["id", "fecha_sin_hora"]).agg(
    nombre=("nombre", "first"),
    entradas_salidas=("hora", "list"),
).apply(create_list).reset_index()

# Crear columnas para entradas y salidas de mañana y tarde
datos_agrupados["entrada1"] = datos_agrupados["entradas_salidas"].apply(
    lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else None
)
datos_agrupados["salida1"] = datos_agrupados["entradas_salidas"].apply(
    lambda x: x[1] if len(x) >= 2 else None
)
datos_agrupados["entrada2"] = datos_agrupados["entradas_salidas"].apply(
    lambda x: x[2] if len(x) >= 3 else None
)
datos_agrupados["salida2"] = datos_agrupados["entradas_salidas"].apply(
    lambda x: x[3] if len(x) >= 4 else None
)

# Eliminar columna auxiliar
del datos_agrupados["entradas_salidas"]

# Reemplazar "archivo_procesado.csv" con el nombre deseado para el archivo nuevo
datos_agrupados.to_csv("archivo_procesado.csv", index=False)


Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Es importante que agregues el código con el que estás intentado resolverlo y  especialmente un ejemplo de tu csv (cabecera y algunas lineas que muestren el problema, por ejemplo varias con datos de Ana). Si hay datos sensibles enmascararlos, lo importante es la estructura y poder reproducir el problema: [mcve]. De la estructura de tu csv y del DataFrame resultante dependerá como proceder para agrupar los datos adecuadamente.

Qué columnas tiene el CSV de entrada?
